# Cannot upload files in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, internet, upload

I'm running CS50's appliance on top of Ubuntu 14.04. The internet seems to be working fine and the download speed is normal too. However, I cannot upload files on the internet. Check50 cannot upload files on the server and returns "unexpected end of input". I took a speed test and found out that my system uploads files for a very short period of time after which it gets stuck.

After banging my head against the wall for an entire week, I've successfully finished dictionary.c, and I desperately want to see those green smiley faces. Please help me out.